# Overlay all screens and draw rectangle with a mouse

Tags: python, user-interface, python-imaging-library, pywin32, beeware

I am working on tiny program to capture screen print, I want to do it in a similar fashion that Win Snipping Tool is working. First I need to overlay all screens with a 50% opacity layer and then, using the mouse, draw a rectangle and read vertices coordinates. Honestly, I have no idea how to bite this. I tried with win32api / gui and it is great to get mouse coordinates, but still was unable to draw a rectangle. My idea (one of many) is to (using PIL / ImageGrab) take shots of both displays, put an overlay and print them as a full screen on all windows, but I failed while doing this. Other idea is to take img grab and create two new windows using BeeWare / Toga (that is GUI framework I am using) in full screen, but I was unable to find any method to open window on second display. Any ideas and hints will be greatly appreciated, I am really counting on you, as I feel I reached dead end.

Comment: *to (using PIL / ImageGrab) take shots of both displays, put an overlay and print them as a full screen on all windows, but I failed while doing this*Why did it failed?What happened?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I am unable to display screen print to overlay desktop. Pil opens the image using default system viewer (and it is pretty slow operation), while I would like to speed it up and embed within my application interface or (most preferably) w/o any additional window and simply put a layer above all opened apps. I can easily take screen print of all screens, but I need a feature to grab only selected rectangle (identically as in SnippingTool)

Comment: Well,I have read about `Toga`.Did it have mouse listen event?Using `tkinter` can be a very easy way.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Toga / Beeware is pretty lightweight and young, there is not much in the documentation, but it is really easy to use (and I have no problem with elements positioning, and that was messy with Tkinter, that is why I do not want to use it). I can install `pyHook` to deal with the mouse. Have you got any idea how to utilize this tool for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Well,It is very easy to use `tkinter`.
Ok,It is the principle when I make my screenshot application:

1. User presses the button to start.
2. Make a new window whose width and height should full cover all the screens,and hide the title bar(If it is had to achieve,maybe use `width=9999` and `height=9999`).
3. Take a screenshot of all the desktop(You can use `ImageGrab.grab((),all_screens=True)`) to do that.
4. Make the screenshot showed in a `Canvas`(I know that `toga` have this widget).
5. Start your mouse listener thread and save the position of pressed.
6. When user moves his mouse,create a rectangle(`toga's Canvas` have a function `rect()`).Maybe use this `rect(pressed_x,pressed_y,move_x,move_y)`.And delete the last rectangle(Then it will always show only one rectangle).
7. When user released his mouse,save the position of released.And use `ImageGrab.grab((pressed_x,pressed_y,released_x,released_y),all_screens=True)` to crop the selected area.
8. If you want to show it in application interface.`toga` has a widget called `ImageView`.You can put the image in it.